# Sequential Erlang misunderstanding

Tags: erlang

I have this example here, I run it with 1, [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1]

```
example(_, []) -> [];
example(X, [X | Rest]) -> Rest;
example(X, [Y | Rest]) -> [Y | example(X, Rest)].
```

In my head (that is attached to my body) I get [2,3,4] but the compiler says [2,3,1,4,1]. How come? Either I am too tired or I don't understand this stuff correctly.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Well, since your first parameter matches the head of the list the second overload is used, leading to `Rest`, which is `[2,3,1,4,1]`, ending the "recursion". As always, the compiler is right ;)

Maybe you wanted to write `example(X, [X | Rest]) -> example(X, Rest)` instead? That would indeed remove all `1`s and not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

Clauses are matched from top to bottom.

You call `example(1, [1,2,3,1,4,1])`.

First, erlang will try to match agains `(_,[])`. This will fail because your second argument isn't empty list.

Second match will be against `(X,[X | Rest)`. `X` becomes bounded to `1`, so the second parameter "is" now `[1 | Rest]`. This will success the match against `[1,2,3,1,4,1]`, because first list item is `1` (value of `X`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
example(_, []) -> [];
example(X, [X | Rest]) -> example(X, Rest);
example(X, [Y | Rest]) -> [Y | example(X, Rest)].
```

`wy:example(1, [1,2,3,1,1]).` will remove all the elment 1.

Comment: This one is 3 hours late and includes absolutely no additional info compared to the existing answers by Krab and me.